# How does first order logic and linear algebra correlate?

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, first-order-logic

I did a course in my university concerning mathematical logic. Now we started a course about linear algebra. I wonder how those two mathematics correlate to each other (meaning first order logic and linear algebra)? For example when doing a proof in linear algebra, does it has an equivalence in first order logic? Could I check validity of those theorems in linear algebra purely by checking whether a theorem is true always when all axioms are true? Another question is: If I prove that some formula is a theorem of some linear algebra axioms, do we say that this theorem is true? Or do we say that a theorem is true only if we talk about some particular model? And what could be an example of that model in linear algebra?

note: I wonder about this because when doing proofs in linear algebra, we don't always use the first order logic notation. We use other mathematical notation and often even just a natural language. That's where my confusion comes from (because in first order logic we used semantic trees for proving that some formula is a logical consequence of some set of axioms).

Comment: For any field $k$, there's a first-order theory whose models are vector spaces over $k$. If you want to do this "single-sorted" you write down an operation for every scalar in $k$ corresponding to scalar multiplication by that scalar, then write down all the vector space axioms. Statements you can prove from those axioms are true for all vector spaces and that's what you're doing in a rigorous course in linear algebra.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, when we talk about some specific vector space and what is true for that vector space, we talk about a specific model of the vector space axioms. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Note that this first-order theory is very limited in some sense; it can talk about linear dependence and independence of a finite set of vectors but it can't talk directly about, for example, linear transformations! To model those we'd need a bigger theory.

Comment: I also wonder: When doing a proof in my course on linear algebra, we don't use any formal proofs (for example similar to those in Hilbert axiomatic system). We simply use natural language to persuade the reader (but we couldn't use these kind of informal proofs in a computer that doesn't understand semantics). Do mathematicians also use some formal systems for proving theorems in linear algebra? Or do they just rely on informal proofs?

Comment: You could do it all formally from the vector space axioms if you wanted to; how close you get to that style depends on how rigorous the course and professor are. Generally mathematicians do this sort of thing at some point in their educations and then convince themselves they could fill in the details if they needed to and don’t bother after that. This post by Terence Tao could be a useful read: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/theres-more-to-mathematics-than-rigour-and-proofs/

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Another example of the limitations of sticking to the first-order language of vector spaces: you can say “this vector space has dimension $n$” (exercise) but you can’t say “every vector space has a unique and well-defined dimension.”

Comment: Don't we call the latter theorem a meta-theorem?

Comment: Any mathematician you talk to would just call it a theorem.

Comment: To proof such a theorem, would we need than a second-order language? Or how should I imagine in simple terms this expansion of a theory?

Comment: I honestly haven't thought about it. It's a statement we can formalize in first-order ZFC (since in first-order ZFC we can now quantify over sets) but basically nobody writes down formalizations of results like these in first-order ZFC.